# all my commit are gone, overwritten. can I reverse

Tags: git, github

My whole week of work is gone. This is what happened:

I haven't updated my github for a week. And I added a lot of stuff, so just now I decided to open window git gui. Did a stage, then commit, then push.
Then I remember when I pushed I had an error `window name push_setup already exist`.

After that I closed everything (including my Atom editor) and did a git gui push again, and it said everything was up-to-date. I then check github and nothing was changed. 
Then I did the following on cmd git without thinking cause I was too tired

```
git checkout quoteBranch   
git merge quoteBranch
```

I must have overwrote everything. What should I do, someone help. Sorry if my wording are messy, Im in a panic. Please someone help, please is there a way to reverse

Comment: Do not panic. Your work is not lost and if you proceed carefully you should be able to recover everything.

Comment: Read this full answer for some other options if you run into detached HEAD when you restore commits with reflog. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716

Comment: omg thank you i got my files back!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check your log to see if you have your commits in the log.
If not use the ref log below.

You can recover any content which was **added** to the staging area even if you did not commit.

Git track content when its added to the staging area so it can be restored.

Here is where git reflog is come to rescue you.

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

`git reflog`  will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

Comment: Hi so I did relog and got a lot of Head as shown. Do I just do git checkout HEAD@{1}.  if the HEAD{0} is the one that deleted everything??

Comment: `git checkout` will get you a "detached head", you probably want `git reset`.

Comment: Find out which one was the last good one and check it out. it should be one of the first ones i assume, since you did it just now.

Comment: so I should do git reset HEAD@{1} instead?

Comment: Agreed. here is how to fix a detached head http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716

Comment: You need to find out which one you need. read the reflog and go back to the point before the merge,

Comment: omg thank you so much I got my files back. I was freaking out my brain wasnt functioning. I thought i lost everything, I should really read the doc properly before I do anything

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Read the full answer above to learn more about detached HEAD.